# React this.setState function gives error when try to set new state value

Tags: reactjs

When I try to update state of component with this.setState function (with or without callback) it gives following warning followed by an error as shown below.

**Warning**: An update (setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate) was scheduled from inside an update function. Update functions should be pure, with zero side-effects. Consider using componentDidUpdate or a callback.

**Uncaught TypeError**: itemValue.toLowerCase is not a function

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactAutocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';
export default class AddMedicine extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        autocompleteData: props.list,
        bid: '',
        formId: '',
        formsOfBrand: []
    };

    this.renderBrandItem = this.renderBrandItem.bind(this);
    this.onChangeBrand = this.onChangeBrand.bind(this);
    this.onSelectBrand = this.onSelectBrand.bind(this);
    this._getFormsByBID = this._getFormsByBID.bind(this);

    this.renderFormItem = this.renderFormItem.bind(this);
    this.onChangeForm = this.onChangeForm.bind(this);
    this.onSelectForm = this.onSelectForm.bind(this);

}

renderBrandItem(item, highlighted) {
    return <div
                key={item.bid}
                style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#eee' : 'transparent'}}
            >
                {item.brand_name}
            </div>

}

onChangeBrand(e) { this.setState({
        bid: e.target.value,
        formsOfBrand : ['dd', 'dfsd']
    })
}

onSelectBrand(bid) {
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
            let newState = {...prevState};
            newState.bid = bid;
            newState.formsOfBrand = this._getFormsByBID(bid);
            console.log(newState);
            return newState;
    });
}

componentDidUpdate() {}


_getFormsByBID(id){
   let brand = this.state.autocompleteData.filter(brand => {
            console.log(brand); console.log(id);
            return (brand.bid == id)? true : false; }
       );
    brand = brand[0];
   console.log(brand);
   return brand.forms;
}

renderFormItem(item, highlighted) {
    return <div
        key={Object.keys(item)[0]}
        style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#eee' : 'transparent'}}
    >
        {item[Object.keys(item)[0]]}
    </div>

}

onChangeForm(e) { this.setState({ formId: e.target.value }) }

onSelectForm(formId) { this.setState({ formId: formId }) }

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <ReactAutocomplete
                items={this.state.autocompleteData}
                getItemValue={item => item.bid}
                renderItem={this.renderBrandItem}
                value={this.state.bid}
                onSelect={this.onSelectBrand}
            />


            <select>
                {this.state.formsOfBrand.forEach((form) =>
                    <option value={Object.keys(form)[0]}>{form[Object.keys(form)[0]]}</option>
                )}
            </select>

        </React.Fragment>


    )
}
```

}

Comment: Add code for `this._getFormsByBID()`

Comment: `onSelect` needs an argument.  You have this: `onSelect={this.onSelectBrand}`....don't you need this: `onSelect={bid => this.onSelectBrand(bid)}`?

Comment: @SethLutske no, that is ok so long as `onSelect` is being passed the value `onSelectBrand` expects. Mohsin, can you include the code where the error for `itemValue.toLowerCase` is occurring? If it isn't too much trouble you may as well share the entire component code for `AddMedicine`.

Comment: @DrewReese I added complete code under question description. Actually error  itemValue.toLowerCase is from inside react-autocomplete (https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete) . I am sure I am making small silly mistake which I am not able to figure it out. I appreciate your help.

Qiarash I have this function already in place.

Comment: If the error is emanating from `react-autocomplete` then perhaps you're not passing data in the correct type, `string`. We can dig into it.

Comment: @DrewReese i am passing data in required format as you can see onselect needs a callback function. onSelect={this.onSelectBrand} . As in provided code under question description, if I remove setState function call inside onSelectBrand function then this error will not occur. so issue is with this setState call. Thank you

Comment: Is this the entire component code? Why do you `this.state.formsOfBrand.forEach` instead of mapping the options? I see references to some "form" but no form code. Have you examined [Autocomplete.js::maybeAutoCompleteText:L392-413](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/41388f7d7760bf6cf38e7946e43d4fddd9c7c176/lib/Autocomplete.js#L392-L413)? Line 405 is where the error occurs, backtrack from there to ensure the values it looks at are type `string`.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, this is the entire code of component. Let me add that even if I remove select element which has  this.state.formsOfBrand.forEach, still its the same error. I don't know why this setState method call inside onSelectBrand generating this error. Is it due to I missed something to add or mis-configured

Comment: What does `onSelectForm(formId)` or `onChangeForm(e)` do? Nothing calls them. Your `<select>` has no handlers either. Have you tried clearing out all the extraneous code, distill it down to the minimum to reproduce the issue? The code I linked previously uses the passed `getItemValue` prop, so I think your `bid`'s may not be strings to `toLowerCase` on. Try adding a breakpoint or some logging in that function.

Comment: those were for <select> element which I removed